# How can we use a third party font in RDLC on Azure app service?

Tags: asp.net, fonts, azure-web-app-service, rdlc, localreport

We have an application that uses a bar code font within an RDLC report, and we want to migrate this from a VM to Azure app services (formerly web apps).  The issue here is that we obviously don't have the ability to install the font.  I am pretty sure RDLC uses GDI+ to render the reports, so I was hoping I could find a method/property on the LocalReport that would give me the ability to set some sort of PrivateFontCollection, but I have hit a brick wall.

So I guess I have a couple questions that might help get this figured out, otherwise we will need to come up with another reporting solution:

1. Is there a generic way to temporarily install a font in .NET that can be used by the current application?
2. Is there a way to specify a PrivateFontCollection anywhere in a LocalReport object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDLC report refer to the font by the family name. To use a third party font, we have to actually install the font on your production machine.

Here is feedback from SQL Server Reporting Services team.

[The ReportViewer's rendering extensions do not support PrivateFontCollection.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/541241/rdlc-report-parser-ignores-addfontresource-and-privatefontcollection)

As a workaround, you could generate the barcode into a image without using private font and put the image on your RDLC report. Here is a source code and test code to generate a barcode image file.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BarCodeGenerator barCode = new BarCodeGenerator("123456789012345");
        barCode.SaveImage("F:\\abc.jpeg");
    }
}

public class BarCodeGenerator
{
    public BarCodeGenerator(string code, int barHeight = 200, int imageWidth = 420, int imageHeigth = 240)
    {
        _barCode = code;
    }

    public void SaveImage(string filePath)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, Width, Height);

        String intercharacterGap = "0";
        String str = '*' + _barCode.ToUpper() + '*';
        int strLength = str.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < _barCode.Length; i++)
        {
            if (alphabet39.IndexOf(_barCode[i]) == -1 || _barCode[i] == '*')
            {
                g.DrawString("INVALID BAR CODE TEXT", new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Red, 10, 10);
                return;
            }
        }

        String encodedString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
                encodedString += intercharacterGap;

            encodedString += coded39Char[alphabet39.IndexOf(str[i])];
        }

        int encodedStringLength = encodedString.Length;
        int widthOfBarCodeString = 0;
        double wideToNarrowRatio = 3;


        if (align != AlignType.Left)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < encodedStringLength; i++)
            {
                if (encodedString[i] == '1')
                    widthOfBarCodeString += (int)(wideToNarrowRatio * (int)weight);
                else
                    widthOfBarCodeString += (int)weight;
            }
        }

        int x = 0;
        int wid = 0;
        int yTop = 0;
        SizeF hSize = g.MeasureString(headerText, headerFont);
        SizeF fSize = g.MeasureString(_barCode, footerFont);

        int headerX = 0;
        int footerX = 0;

        if (align == AlignType.Left)
        {
            x = leftMargin;
            headerX = leftMargin;
            footerX = leftMargin;
        }
        else if (align == AlignType.Center)
        {
            x = (Width - widthOfBarCodeString) / 2;
            headerX = (Width - (int)hSize.Width) / 2;
            footerX = (Width - (int)fSize.Width) / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            x = Width - widthOfBarCodeString - leftMargin;
            headerX = Width - (int)hSize.Width - leftMargin;
            footerX = Width - (int)fSize.Width - leftMargin;
        }

        if (showHeader)
        {
            yTop = (int)hSize.Height + topMargin;
            g.DrawString(headerText, headerFont, Brushes.Black, headerX, topMargin);
        }
        else
        {
            yTop = topMargin;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < encodedStringLength; i++)
        {
            if (encodedString[i] == '1')
                wid = (int)(wideToNarrowRatio * (int)weight);
            else
                wid = (int)weight;

            g.FillRectangle(i % 2 == 0 ? Brushes.Black : Brushes.White, x, yTop, wid, height);

            x += wid;
        }

        yTop += height;

        if (showFooter)
            g.DrawString(_barCode, footerFont, Brushes.Black, footerX, yTop);

        g.Flush();
        using (FileStream stream = File.Create(filePath))
        {
            bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }  
    }

    private string alphabet39 = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-. $/+%*";

    private string[] coded39Char =
    {
        /* 0 */ "000110100", 
        /* 1 */ "100100001", 
        /* 2 */ "001100001", 
        /* 3 */ "101100000",
        /* 4 */ "000110001", 
        /* 5 */ "100110000", 
        /* 6 */ "001110000", 
        /* 7 */ "000100101",
        /* 8 */ "100100100", 
        /* 9 */ "001100100", 
        /* A */ "100001001", 
        /* B */ "001001001",
        /* C */ "101001000", 
        /* D */ "000011001", 
        /* E */ "100011000", 
        /* F */ "001011000",
        /* G */ "000001101", 
        /* H */ "100001100", 
        /* I */ "001001100", 
        /* J */ "000011100",
        /* K */ "100000011", 
        /* L */ "001000011", 
        /* M */ "101000010", 
        /* N */ "000010011",
        /* O */ "100010010", 
        /* P */ "001010010", 
        /* Q */ "000000111", 
        /* R */ "100000110",
        /* S */ "001000110", 
        /* T */ "000010110", 
        /* U */ "110000001", 
        /* V */ "011000001",
        /* W */ "111000000", 
        /* X */ "010010001", 
        /* Y */ "110010000", 
        /* Z */ "011010000",
        /* - */ "010000101", 
        /* . */ "110000100", 
        /*' '*/ "011000100",
        /* $ */ "010101000",
        /* / */ "010100010", 
        /* + */ "010001010", 
        /* % */ "000101010", 
        /* * */ "010010100"
    };

    public enum AlignType
    {
        Left, Center, Right
    }

    public enum BarCodeWeight
    {
        Small = 1, Medium, Large
    }

    private AlignType align = AlignType.Center;
    private string _barCode = "1234567890";
    private int leftMargin = 10;
    private int topMargin = 20;
    private int height = 200;
    private bool showHeader = false;
    private bool showFooter = false;
    private String headerText = "BarCode Demo";
    private BarCodeWeight weight = BarCodeWeight.Small;
    private Font headerFont = new Font("Courier", 18);
    private Font footerFont = new Font("Courier", 8);

    private int _height = 240;
    public int Height
    {
        get { return _height; }
        set { _height = value; }
    }

    private int _width = 420;
    public int Width
    {
        get { return _width; }
        set { _width = value; }
    }
}
```

Here is the barcode image generated by upper code.

[image]